# How to share fluent configuration in a Castle Windsor IOC container

Tags: wcf, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, unity-container

I am trying to create an IOC container in Castle Windsor that's configuration is shared across assemblies.

**(What follows is an example of how this works in Unity. What I want to do is to make it work the same way using Castle Windsor)**

I have the following project configuration...

```
TestCompany.Services.Host
    (Web project hosting a number of .svc files)
    PrintService.svc
    Web.Config
    Unity.Config

TestCompany.Services.PrintService
     IPrintService.cs
     PrintService.cs
```

The actual implementation of my "PrintService" is not implemented inside my Services.Host but in the TestCompany.Services.PrintService assembly.

As part of my shared project code (not shown) I have a container helper which is responsible for loading the unity configuration...

```
public static IUnityContainer GetContainer()
{
    // Checks for existance of container (_container == null) ommitted.
    var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity") as UnityConfigurationSection;
    section.Configure(_container, name);
    ...
    ...
}
```

This method loads the unity configuration section from the Unity.Config and uses it to configure the container.

The advantage of this method is that one Unity.Config loaded inside (I presume) the AppDomain can service a number of assemblies. Simply calling GetContainer() from any of the assemblies consumed by my service host will return a container populated with the same type resolution's etc.

I really want to use the fluent configuration in Castle Windsor but I dont see how without this "shared" configuration file that can be acheived. PrintService and any future services will all need to resolve the same dependencies and I dont want to have to repeat my fluent configuration between these services.

Ideally I need some sort of container configured in the service host app that can "flow" into all of the assemblies that it makes use of.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using two different container frameworks, at the same time?

Comment: I'm not, I am trying to demonstrate what I want to do in Castle by giving an example of how it was done in Unity. Question has been editied to clarify#

Answer (score 0):

I think I may not be understanding your question but I think I understand your scenario and here is how I do something similar, if it helps at all...

My Philosophy:

> Each part of the application should be in charge of registering what
>   it knows about and nothing more, so there is no need for a single
>   central configuration file and things that are shared between
>   components are registered in one place and their interfaces are
>   available everywhere via a common library.

So let's take an example...

First of all, let us just say (for the purposes of my example) that IPrintService is something that you want to register an implementation of once and use throughout the application and that we have some other component that needs to be implemented by some external module from the main application.  We, therefore, create an assembly called Common like so:

**Common**

```
public interface IPrintService
{
    void Print();
}

public interface IMyService
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Now let us think about the main part of the application (maybe it is an ASP .NET application, maybe justa console application, does not really matter).  Here we construct the container and ask it to find all the possible components.  We can do that like so:

**Main Application**

```
// Could be the Global.asax code behind but for simplicity this is 
// just a console application
class Program
{

    private static readonly IWindsorContainer Mycontainer 
        = BootstrapContainer();


    // Allow access to the raw container - this is probably a bad idea but
    // in the rare case that you need it you can get it from here        
    public static IWindsorContainer Container { get { return Mycontainer; } }

    private static IWindsorContainer BootstrapContainer()
    {
        // Here we will just install every IWindsorInstaller found in any
        // assembly in the same folder as the application (so no need for
        // references or anything).
        var c = new WindsorContainer();
        string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        c.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(folder)));
        return c;
    } 
}

// Here is the print service implementation
public class MyPrintService : IPrintService
{
    public void Print()
    {
        // Print!
    }
}

// This is the installer for the main module - here we are saying exactly 
// what is implementing the interface
public class MainApplicationInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, 
                        IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container
            .Register(Component
                          .For<IPrintService>()
                          .ImplementedBy<MyPrintService>());
    }
}
```

So now we have a common library with our shared inetrfaces and a main application that will register an implementation for our shared interface and also load up any other modules in the system.

The only thing, therefore, left to do is to consume that print service and use it.  We can do this anywhere that is using the container so let's create a third assembly that references **only** Common (we will call it test module.

**Test Module**

```
// This installer installs just the things inside this module since that
// is all it knows about but those things can use things that are 
// registered in the container by anybody.
public class TestModuleInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, 
                        IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container
            .Register(Component
                          .For<IMyService>()
                          .ImplementedBy<MyServiceThatDoesSomething>());
    }
}

public class MyServiceThatDoesSomething : IMyService
{
    private readonly IPrintService _printService;

    public MyServiceThatDoesSomething(IPrintService printService)
    {
        _printService = printService;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Use the print service!
        _printService.Print();
    }
}
```

Finally compile everything and copy the test module to the same folder as the main application and then from the main you can do this:

```
Container.Resolve<IMyService>().DoSomething();
```

And then the magic happens!  Well, some code runs and you find that the print service is called by the class from the module even though it knows nothing about it.

Anyway, maybe that helps a little bit, maybe not, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This certainly helps a lot. However, one thing I am looking to do is to have a WCF application that has one implmenetation of PrintService and a test application that has another implementation. Likewise the container should "flow" (that is objects should be able to be resoloved) from components inside the PrintService as well.

Comment: In that scenario you can have two "installers" (IWindsorInstaller implementations) - one that you have inside your test application that registers one version of IPrintService and another inside your WCF application that registers a different version of IPrintService.  I am not sure what you mean by flow - once a component is registered with the container it can have dependencies on anything else that is also registered with the container (irrespective of assembly) by just adding properties or ctor arguments (or get a static reference  to the container and resolve that way if you need to).